# Variation for operators

Tags: operator-theory, calculus-of-variations

The variation for a *real-valued* functional is a way to find its stationary points. How does this work for an *operator-valued* functional? What does it mean to vary an operator and say for an operator-valued functional $J$ the condition $\delta J = 0$?

Comment: Ordering on operators?

Comment: For linear operators on an Hilbertspace. More precise for linear operators which acts on wavefunctions (like H, p, q).